# What does the cookiePolicy adapter parameter do in Worklight 6.1+?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

The Worklight 6.1 InfoCenter refers to a [cookiePolicy parameter](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_the__connectionpolicy__element.html&resultof%3D%2522%2563%256f%256f%256b%2569%2565%2570%256f%256c%2569%2563%2579%2522%2520%2522%2563%256f%256f%256b%2569%2565%2570%256f%256c%2569%2563%2569%2522%2520) which can be set on an HTTP adapter. It mentions four possible values, but doesn't go into details about what they do. Is it safe to assume they all preserve cookies they are returned from the back-end HTTP service? How does that relate (if at all) to the JSESSIONID cookie that may be shared between the Worklight server and any back-end server? Do all calls from that adapter share the same cookie state, or does it depend on the security realm being used?

Answer (score 1):

The `cookiePolicy` parameter in a HTTP adapter defines the way the adapter's HTTP client handles the cookies returned by the backend.

These cookies don't affect the JSESSIONID cookie returned by the application server to the client (mobile app).
The policy relates to all the cookies returned by the backend server to Worklight, including JSESSIONID.

To read more about each option, refer to the relevant IETF documentation for the specific standard.

Comment: Idan, thanks. I should have been clearer - though - I wasn't referring to the JSESSION ID from the app - I was referring to any (potential) JSESSION (which is a cookie, of course) returned from the back-end service. How will that relate to that adapter and any subsequent calls it makes? Is the same JSESSION then used by all calls from that adapter?

Answer (score 0):

To answer (one of) my own questions, I have confirmed that in Worklight 6.2, each adapter has a separate instance of an HttpClient, and so the cookiePolicy acts only within the scope of one adapter. Different adapters will not share cookies by configuration.